# Xamarin Android get imageuri?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm developing a wallpaper app in xamarin forms. I'm setting the wallpaper with xamarin android. I figured out how to set the wallpaper to a resource id but now I want to start an activity to crop and set it.
I can get an intent from the WallpaperManager class but I need to give an imageuri as a parameter and I don t know how I can get the URI of an image in the resource. I have tried several things from the internet but nothing worked for me :(

Code:

```
var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("image/W0.jpg");
                Intent intent =  wallpaperManager.GetCropAndSetWallpaperIntent(uri);
                Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

Comment: You need to copy it to a public place on the phone, like the SDCard

Comment: Ok I will try it